# SONY VAIO Windows 8 freezes, then a blue screen with a message and restarts continuous loop

Tags: windows, sony-vaio

I'm having problems with my SONY VAIO laptop, it worked fine until one day I went to turn it on and was faced with this message: "Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart, we're just collecting some error info and then we'll restart for you." and just turns into a continuous loop.

The laptop starts up as normal and loads up to the home screen, then it freezes and I am unable to move my mouse, that's when the blue screen comes up with that message and restarts.

I purchased this laptop in February second hand, and the guy sold many laptops.

I have tried to contact him and he hasn't got back to me so stuck on what to do.

I have tried taking out the battery and no luck, I tried to do system restore but needed a password, which I do not have the guy who sold it to me does (I would think). I don't have a windows 8 disc either.

If anyone could please help me I would really appreciate it, really need this laptop for work.

Comment: Its a serious issue I doubt you can solve, get in touch with the seller if you can.

Comment: Hold F8 and select "Disable automatic restart on system failure". See if you can boot into WinRE and grab the crash dumps, and post them online so that we can analyze them.

Comment: There should be an error code with lots of capital letters and underscores below the ran-into-a-problem text. That code is the most important part of the BSOD.

Answer (score 0):

First, do you have logs? If so put them up here.

Try booting to Safe Mode using either Shift-F8 or just F8, but this might not work if your machine is too fast. If it boots to Safe Mode then shut off anything third party that runs on boot, and try again.

Or buy a SATA --> USB cable off Ebay (check the HDD is SATA first), yank the HDD, copy your personal files (I'm assuming you don't have any backups?), wipe the disk and put a fresh install of win8 on it.

The fact that it fully boots suggests that it's not a hardware problem.